# Is there a way to increase space between connections and ground planes in eagle?

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, short-circuit

The below picture is a screen shot from eagle. The red shade means gnd.
Is there a way to increase the space between where the connection goes and the red, gnd, plane?

I'm paranoid I'm going to solder over the small gaps shown and cause a short to gnd.

Is it possible to increase that space?

[image]

Comment: _"I'm paranoid I'm going to solder over the small gaps"_ - do you have a solder mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done using the "Isolate" setting of the plane (right-click -> properties -> Isolate).

The setting specifies the minimum distance from the plane fill to any other copper. Making this value larger will increase the spacing.